# Implementação Merge Sort Externo em C

Tags: c, classificação

Estou precisando implementar Merge Sort Externo no meu código, e já tentei procurar, mas não consigo achar, podem me ajudar? No meu código eu preciso ler um arquivo, inserir, atualizar, remover que ainda nao fiz, usar tabela hash, e ordenar em merge sort externo e k-way merge, que foi outro que também não conseguir, são dois arquivos de 10mb de entrada. Estou com dificuldade de implantar Merge Sort Externo, pois só acho trabalhando com vetor, e o meu é um typedef que carrega 3 arquivos, com 4 elementos em cada linha, a chave para ordenar é o nome ([0]).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXTAB 1131071
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct{
    char nome[128], tel[128], cid[128], pais[128];
    int ocupado;
}Elemento;

struct arquivo{
    FILE *f;
    int pos, MAX, *buffer;
};

Elemento tabHash[MAXTAB];

int h(char *chave){
    int i, soma=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(chave);i++){
        soma+=abs(chave[i])*pow((i+1), 1);
    }
    return soma%MAXTAB;
}

void InicializaTabHash(Elemento tabHash[], int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        tabHash[i].ocupado=false;
    }
}

int create(Elemento tabHash[], Elemento e){
    int pos=h(e.nome);
    if(tabHash[pos].ocupado==false){
        tabHash[pos]=e;
        tabHash[pos].ocupado=true;
        return true;
    }else{
        printf("ocorreu uma colisão\n");
        return false;
    }
}

void imprimirPessoa(Elemento p){
    printf("\n\tNome: %s", p.nome);
    printf("\n\tTelefone: %s", p.tel);
    printf("\n\tCidade: %s", p.cid);
    printf("\n\tPais: %s", p.pais);
}

//Leitura dos dados de uma Pessoa
Elemento lerPessoa(){
    Elemento p;
    printf("\nNome: ");
    scanf("%s", p.nome);
    printf("Telefone: ");
    scanf("%s", p.tel);
    printf("Cidade: ");
    scanf("%s", p.cid);
    printf("Pais: ");
    scanf("%s", p.pais);
    return p;
}

int funcaoHash(int chave){
  return chave % MAXTAB;
}

void inserir(Elemento t[]){
    Elemento p = lerPessoa();
    int id = h(p.nome);
    while(strlen(t[id].nome) > 0){
        id = funcaoHash(id + 1);
    }
    t[id] = p;
}

Elemento* busca(Elemento t[], char chave[]){
    int id = h(chave);
    while(strlen(t[id].nome) > 0){
        if(strcmp(chave, t[id].nome) == 0){
            return &t[id];
        }else
            id = funcaoHash(id + 1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void CarregaAgenda(Elemento tabHash[]){
    char nomeArq[100];
    fflush(stdout);
    Elemento e;
    FILE *fp;
    int nc=0, ni=0, t=0;
    if((fp=fopen("teste2.csv","r"))!=NULL){
        while(!feof(fp)){
            t++;
            fscanf(fp,"%[^,],", e.nome);
            fscanf(fp,"%[^,],", e.tel);
            fscanf(fp,"%[^,],", e.cid);
            fscanf(fp,"%[^,],\n", e.pais);
            if(create(tabHash, e)){
                ni++;
            }else{
                nc++;
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("Ocorreram %d insercoes e %d colisoes \n", ni, nc);
    }else{
        printf("Erro ao abrir.\n");
    }
}

void atualizar(Elemento tabHash[], char nome[]){
    Elemento *buscar = busca(tabHash, nome), p;
    int opcao;
    if(buscar){
        printf("\tNome encontrado:\n");
        imprimirPessoa(*buscar);
        printf("\t\nO que vai ser atualizado:\n\t1 - Telefone\n\t2 - Cidade\n\t3 - Pais\n\tNumero: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        p=*buscar;
        if (opcao==1){
            printf("Telefone: ");
            scanf("%s", p.tel);
        }else if (opcao==2){
            printf("Cidade: ");
            scanf("%s", p.cid);
        }else if (opcao==3){
            printf("Pais: ");
            scanf("%s", p.pais);
        }
        imprimirPessoa(p);
    }else
        printf("\tNome nao encontrado!\n");
}


Elemento delete(Elemento tabHash[], char *chave){
    int pos;
    pos=h(chave);
    if(tabHash[pos].ocupado==true){
        if(strcmp(tabHash[pos].nome, chave)==0){
            tabHash[pos].ocupado=false;
        }
    }
    return tabHash[pos];
}

int main(){
    Elemento e, *buscar;
    InicializaTabHash(tabHash, MAXTAB);
    CarregaAgenda(tabHash); 
    //inserir(tabHash); //inserir pronto
    /*char nome[128];
    printf("\tQual nome deseja buscar? ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", nome);
    buscar = busca(tabHash, nome);
    if(buscar){
        printf("\tNome encontrado:\n");
        imprimirPessoa(*buscar);
    }else
        printf("\tNome nao encontrado!\n");*/ //buscar pronto
    /*char nome[128];
    printf("\tQual nome deseja atualizar? ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", nome);
    atualizar(tabHash, nome);*/ //atualizar pronto
}
```

Comment: _Estou com dificuldade de implantar Merge Sort Externo, pois só acho trabalhando com vetor, e o meu é um typedef que carrega 3 arquivos_ Chega uma hora em que você não _acha_ as coisas e precisa afinal criar, programar. Há muito material sobe esse sort nos livros de estruturas de dados. O que fez para _procurar_? Tentou os clássicos como **Data Structures And Algorithms** de Aho, Hopcroft e Ulmann? Programe uma coisa de cada vez. Está complicando tudo. E use uma função _factory_ para gerar os registros. Usar um registro e não uma letra não faz diferença: apenas use uma função de comparação.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer Merge Sort em um arquivo ou fazê-lo em um vetor em memória RAM é basicamente o mesmo algoritmo. A diferença é somente na manipulação dos registros. Em um vetor `v` o acesso a um elemento `i` é:

```
printf("%i\n", v[i]);  //assumindo que o vetor é do tipo inteiro
```

Para uma estrutura em RAM:

```
printf("%i\n", v[i].campo_inteiro);
```

Para arquivo em disco, basta criar umas funções de apoio que façam a mesma coisa. Para acesso ao valor:

```
printf("%i\n", getValue(fp, i));  //assumindo que os dados no disco são do tipo inteiro
```

Para uma estrutura em disco:

```
estru = getStruct(fp, i);
printf("%i\n", estru.campo_inteito);
```

Para fazer as idas e vindas no arquivo, use: `fsetpos()`, `fgetpos()`, `rewind()`.

Para as leituras e escritas no arquivo, use: `fread()`, `fwrite()`, para estruturas e pode usar `fscanf()` para os tipos comuns.

Claro que o arquivo deve estar no formato adequado. Por exemplo, se ele for uma coleção de valores separados por vírgulas (csv),então você deve providenciar o correto tratamento do arquivo ou usar uma biblioteca.

Comment: Não, não é a mesma coisa. Nada tem a ver. O `merge` nesse caso trata da intercalação de registros de arquivos distintos. Consulte algum livro. Um exemplo seria classificar um arquivo com 12 milhões de registros quando na memória só puder ter 80. É preciso algum *merge* para colocar os dados em ordem porque são usados vários arquivos já que os dados não cabem na memória de uma vez.